# Does LeaveCriticalSection() flushes the cached variables to memory?

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi

Say I have the following code:

```
// global variable
int i = 0;

...

EnterCriticalSection(&CriticalSection);
i = 45;
i = 24;
i = 32;
LeaveCriticalSection(&CriticalSection);
```

Can the CPU cache the variable `i`, and when `i` is modified, the cached copy is the one modified, and when `LeaveCriticalSection()` is called, the cached value of `i` is flushed to memory (so that for example other threads can see the updated value)?

Comment: It can do anything so long as the observable behaviour of the program matches what the C Standard specifies for the code

Comment: @HarryJohnston The latest C standard does cover multi-threading.  Whether OP's compiler complies with the standard is another matter, but the standard is always designed with existing implementations in mind

Comment: @HarryJohnston Yes I'm sure. The compiler has knowledge of what the CPU does and generates assembly accordingly

Comment: @Christopher, in practice, `LeaveCriticalSection` introduces a memory barrier, so all cached writes will be flushed to memory before it returns.  This behaviour isn't documented, but if it were to change, pretty much every multi-thread application on the planet would break.

Comment: @Harry Johnston I don't know much about memory barriers, but shouldn't a memory barrier be immediately below the code (in this case the memory barrier is not immediately below the code, it is inside the `LeaveCriticalSection(`) function)?

Comment: @Christopher, no, it doesn't matter.  Once you have successfully entered the same critical section in another thread, that thread will always see `i = 32`.

Comment: @Harry Johnston So the CPU can cache variables the way it wants, but once it reaches a memory barrier, it flushes the cache to memory? (is a memory barrier a machine language instruction like `mov` for example?),

Comment: A memory barrier is generally implemented as a machine language instruction, yes.  The details vary depending on the CPU architecture.

Comment: @Harry Johnston So can we assume that the `LeaveCriticalSection()` implementation contains this memory barrier instruction?

Comment: @M.M., the code as posted will work as desired for older C compilers, including all versions of Visual Studio. I'd be seriously worried if it broke on newer compilers, no matter what C11 says.

Comment: @Christopher, yes, I believe that is a safe assumption.  Partly because you can't realistically implement critical sections without memory barriers, but mostly because of the amount of existing code that makes that same assumption.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: 1) As most operating systems don't support the WinAPI, I doubt that "pretty much every multi-thread application on the planet would break". 2) A lot of old C code will break on modern compilers, as they were written without caring about effective type rules, relied on the standard types having specific width, a specific behaviour of bitshifts which invokes UB, or the modulo-operator behaving other than defined with C99. 3) MSVC does not and never has supported any modern C version. It is stuck at the since 18 years outdated C90.

Comment: @Olaf, (1) in context, I'm sure you realized that I meant Windows applications, was it really necessary to force me to spell it out explicitly? (2) nonetheless, such a severe breaking change would be extremely unfortunate, particularly since the compiler would have to make a deliberate effort to decide that it could reorder memory operations across API calls; (3) yes, that's true; how is it relevant?

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Re 2: You really should have a look at the code modern compilers generate. You might be surprised! If you had fixed that many embedded code written by engineers who relied on the compiler **not** reordering statements, you would think different. Oh and e.g. gcc knows most functions of the standard library and **will** apply very aggressive optimisations. Replacinf `printf` with `puts` when appropriate is just a minor (and not even gcc-specific). Re 3: It is relevant, as mentioning C11 for a compiler wich does not even support modern C, less C11 is not an argument.

Comment: @Olaf, of course the compiler will reorder statements, but if it reorders a memory operation across a call to an API function it had better darned well know what that API function actually does, and if it reorders a memory operation across an API function that enters or leaves a critical section, well, IMO that's just pathological.  (And if you'll read what I said more carefully, you'll note that I categorized Visual Studio under "older C compilers", as distinct from C11 compilers.  It was M.M. who brought up C11, I was merely responding to that.)

Comment: @Harry Johnston Is the quotation that **rici** gave from MSDN means that critical sections indeed flushes the cache to memory, or did you already seen this quotation and you think that it is talking about a different behavior?

Comment: Christopher: you might want to read that entire page, since it contains information relevant to your question. Also the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_model_(programming)) and particularly the references in the last paragraph

Comment: @Christopher: Why care about what exactly the hardware does, as long as the observable behaviour is guaranteed? It is not necessary to flush the caches, if the platform supports snooping or other coherency protocols.

Comment: @Christopher: I'd overlooked that page.  Rici's answer is correct, that documents the fact that EnterCriticalSection and LeaveCriticalSection provide memory ordering guarantees.  (As Olaf points out, some platforms might implement this without *actually* flushing the cache from the hardware's perspective, but from the programmer's perspective it will always behave *as if* the cache had been flushed.  The distinction isn't something you need to worry about.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this page from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686355(v=vs.85).aspx)

> The following synchronization functions use the appropriate barriers to ensure memory ordering:
>
> - Functions that enter or leave critical sections.

This doesn't necessarily mean that data is "flushed to memory". Indeed, you might think of certain caches being part of the memory, while other caches might be associated with a single CPU. The "appropriate barriers" do whatever is necessary for the machine architecture to guarantee that all CPUs have a consistent view.

For more information, you might want to start with the Wikipedia pages on [memory barriers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier) and [memory ordering](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_model_(programming)).

Comment: The quoted section does not imply flushing to memory of any kind. What instruction would that be on x86 to start with?

Comment: As long as other threads acquire the same cs, they will never observe anything other than i=32. On top of that, compiler will collapse the assignments and only keep =32. If other threads do not acquire the CS, that's UB. Use std:: atomic, it neatly addresses all concerns.

Comment: @voo: that's a good point and I tried to edit the answer to be a bit more precise, with some links instead of including an essay. Any specific suggestions welcome.

Comment: @sergei: yes, since the variable is not volatile, stores may be elided by compiler optimizations. I thought about mentioning that but it didn't seem relevant. As for `std::atomic`, the question is tagged [tag:c].

Comment: @rici Much better, it's important to understand that "flushing to memory" is just one possible (very bad) strategy to achieve *parts* of what is required. Removed my downvote now that that's clear.

Comment: @rici sure, win32 InterlockedExchange(&i, newval) to assign and InterlockedCompareExchange(&i, 0, 0); to read. Or exchange-add or exhange-or with zeros. Lack of InterlockedRead() makes me cringe.